# How to add get/set properties properly?

Tags: c#, properties, stack-overflow

I have a class and there are some properties in it. I had written the getters and setters for those properties. Here is my code:

```
[DataMember]
public string FullName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Name1, this.Name2); }
    set { FullName = value; }
}
```

But the problem is when I set values to Full Name..

```
var customer = new Customer
{ 
    FullName = customerPhone.Customer.FullName
};
```

It gives the following exception..

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'

How can I write the **set** property correctly?

Comment: In your case, the `FullName` property should only have a getter as it's only supposed to return a string-formatting of two other properties. What's the use of setting `FullName` to "x", when `Name1` is "a" and `Name2` is "b"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the setter. You're not required to have one, and in this case you don't need it.

You're not actually "setting" the value of this public property. You just need a "getter" that returns a full name.

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Name1, this.Name2); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of :

```
set { FullName = value; }
```

you should do a private member called _fullName and write :

```
set { _fullName = value; }
```

this :

```
set { FullName = value; }
```

will call to the set function of the FullName property again which end up with stackoverflow . (endless loop )

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a backind field for this to work. Right now, you are setting FullName to be the value of FullName, causing an infinite loop and thus the exception.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string fullName;

    [DataMember]
   public string FullName
   {
       get { return fullName; }
       set { fullName = value; }
   }
}
```

Also, it doesn't seem to make much sense to allow a SET in a property whose value is calculated..

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `FullName` property recursively, that's why you get the stack overflow. you have 2 choices here.

**Split up the properties** (recommended solution)

Make the `FullName` property read only and only allow the client to call `set` on `Name1` and `Name2`.:

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Name1, this.Name2); }
}

public string Name1 { get; set; }
public string Name2 { get; set; }
```

**Parse the input**

Make the `set` of your `FullName` property able to parse the input:

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Name1, this.Name2); }
    set 
    {
        //Note that this needs validation etc. applying to be robust
        var names = value.Split(" ");
        Name1 = names[0];
        Name2 = names[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed Name2 setting to `names[1]`, it had twice `names[0]`.